# flowtype - How to declare an interface for a package that exports a function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have an import like `import AltContainer from 'alt-container';`. How would you set up a [declaration](http://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#_) for that? The documentation shows how to achieve this for a module that exports functions but there's no example for this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the exports of the module is itself a function, you can declare a function named `exports` from the module.

lib/mymodule.js:

```
declare module "mymodule" {
  declare function exports(foo: string): void;
}
```

index.js

```
import f from "mymodule";
f(0); // error: number ~> string
```

Comment: Great! This is the ticket. :)

Comment: Sorry it took you so long to get a response!

Answer (score -1):

Put something like this in a file in your [`libs`](http://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#libs) directory:

```
declare module 'alt-container' {
  declare function hello(foo: string): number;
}
```

Comment: For some reason a declaration like that raises `^ Library parse error:` and `^ Unexpected token (` for the first `(`. Perhaps it just doesn't support this type of declaration yet? Note that I'm using Flow 0.18.1.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to name the function. Try again.

Comment: The problem is that the module exports a function by default. The solution you are suggesting would work if it exported multiple functions. Then I could name them like that and it would work.

Comment: Ah, that's trickier. You might get better results asking on the #flowtype IRC channel.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a couple of times. No replies so far.